# Json data only loads correct once you refresh the page?

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs

I have two issues but I believe the second issue will be fixed once the first is fixed (question title).

I am receiving JSON from woocommerce. I can call for this data by using `fetch` of course on client side and it looks as such in the code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const response = await fetch('/products');
  const json = await response.json();
  this.setState({
    data: json,
  })
// other code ....
}
```

When I go on the browser I get this error regarding my json data:

```
Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

With the following error in the console.log:

```
index.js:6 GET http://localhost:3000/products 500 (Internal Server Error)
index.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Once the webpage is refreshed...this all disappears, everything becomes A-OKAY, why? and how do I go about rectifying this?

My JSON data when consoled and the page refreshed returns an object - no '<' is there. Also I don't know why I get the 500 error shown above? I am learning node.js - so I think this is a server side issue as I had no issues before I split my code to client and server.

help?

Comment: yes a 500 is a server-side error, so you need to debug the server and find out why it crashes

Comment: Have you tried doing `this.setState({ data: JSON.parse(json) })`?

Comment: Hi @Adam yeah and that does not work and returns a new error. Thanks for the input regardless.

Comment: This error happens because the data you're receiving is HTML or something similar (which starts with `<`) and not JSON.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the input, the server side issue disappears after a refresh it fixes itself - so I'm not sure if its clear cut bug for a lack of a better way of explaining. What is it about a refresh that 'fixes' it I kinda want to understand that if you understand.

Comment: @Adam I understand this reasoning but why after the webpage refresh is it normal JSON and everything is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop this whole refreshing the page issue; I had to fix my server file (node.js of course)

My get request had originally looked like this:

```
let response;
app.get('/products', (req, res, err) => {
  WooCommerce.get('products', function(err, data, res) {
    response = res;
  });
  res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(response));
});
```

The issue here was that I was calling `/products` with fetch which url didn't point to anything but another API call, which only got called once I forced it pass the first url call I guess using a page refresh. Forgive my understanding here.

The correct code was calling Woocommerce api first then passing its response to the `/product` url so I can fetch it in the front end, like so;

```
let response;
  WooCommerce.get('products', function(err, data, res) {
    response = res;
    app.get('/products', (req, res, err) => {
      if (res.status(200)) {
      res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(response));
    } else {
      console.log('theres an error', err);
    }
  })
});
```

And Tarrrrdaaa no refresh issue/SyntaxError error!!!

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the data call you do takes time to load the data. 
Till then the this.state.data is null. The error

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

is because you are trying to process the this.state.data but finds null. You need to make sure you handle what needs to be displayed when data is null.

Also, I think you don't need the await before response.json()
The 500 server error is a server side issue.

Comment: by handling do you suggest I write something like if `this .state.data.length === 0` then do something. So basically the reason it works after a refresh is because it has had time to wait for the data?

Comment: 1. Yes I mean that when I say handling. It should be in the render()
2. Yes, the request completes and it re-renders after a refresh.
3. If you create a codepen with your snippet, I can take a look

Comment: Thank you for your response! https://codesandbox.io/s/yqkk033j1z . I'm not sure on how to make a code pen but will try

Comment: Yeah I made a few changes, lmk if you need further help

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me but I can't see the changes you've made.

Comment: @kadddeee do you see it in the link above?

Comment: Apologises, I've had a look, thank you. it doesn't work the page just 'waits' the data never loads unless the page is refreshed. I believe there is something up with my server.js file, where I am grabbing the data from `Woocommerce.get( url)` and putting this into a `fetch()` so I can use it in the frontend. Something is happening here that I need to figure out. I posted a question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284694/locahost-404-error-regarding-loading-page-images if you would like to take a look also. Thank you for the follow up :)

Answer (score 0):

As one of the answers says, this error happens when you try to parse a nullish value. You can fix this issue by making sure the data is defined before trying to parse it:

```js
if(data){
    JSON.parse(data);
}
```