# locahost 404 error regarding loading page images?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

so I have a loading page which is coded on the index.html file of my reactjs app. 
I also use react router to route my app pages. 
When I visit any route of my app the loading page works. However when I visit a particular route which has props passing through `<Link>` that visits the said route, I get the following console errors;

```
GET http://localhost:3000/product-page/brazilian-wavy-hair/undefined 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/product-page/brazilian-wavy-hair/images/purpleHandsLogo.png
```

The image `purpleHandsLogo.png` does not show. But also why is it being called like a http request? and why is the above error `undefined`. 
When I click on it the 'source' tab highlights `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the index.html.

Whats happening?

I know it may be an issue on the server side but I don't know how to rectify the issue as I am learning as I go in regards to node.js.

This is how my server looks like;

```
const express = require('express');
const WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;



const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://localhost:8888/', // Your store URL
  consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxx', // Your consumer key
  consumerSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', // Your consumer secret
  wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
  version: 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/client/public/index.html'); // change the path to your index.html
});

let response;
app.get('/products', (req, res, err) => {
  WooCommerce.get('products', function(err, data, res) {
    response = res;
  });
  res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(response));
});



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

-----EDIT--------

1) React router block - resides in `app.js` and in the the render of that file:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/contactus" exact component={ContactForm}/>
          <Route path="/shop" exact component={shopLanding}/>
          <Route path="/product-page/"  component={ShopPages}/>)

      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

2) the `<Link>` code:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/product-page/${this.props.slug}/${this.props.idNumber}`,
                  state: {
                    urlId: this.props.idNumber
                  }
                }}>
      <h1 className="typeTitle">{this.props.type}</h1>
      </Link>
```

Comment: Can we see the Link and your Router / Switch block?

Comment: edit abover @mattdevio thanks for your response